# Module not found: Error:Can't resolve 'devextreme/ui/tree_view'

Tags: npm, npm-install

I run npm run build during this error will occur how to solve this

Module not found: Error:Can't resolve 'devextreme/ui/tree_view' in '/home/fawad/pmc-frontend-master@6cd9d075e58/node_modules/devextreme-react'